# No DragNodes displaying under OptionBehavior property to TreeList in DevExpress

Tags: vb.net

I'm using DevExpress TreeList control V18.1 and here I'm unable to find DragNode under OptionBehavior option, I want to know either it has been renamed or has been removed from TreeList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this statement it should help explain what to use now
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T443429/the-treelist-optionsbehavior-dragnode-property-is-now-obsolete-in-v16-1-7

As Requested: in the Link described Dragnode property  is obsolte

```
The DragNodesMode.Multiple or DragNodesMode.Single value indicates that the drag-and-drop functionality is enabled  and also a specific mode is applied.
```

And is recommended to read more about that in the  DragNodesMode documentation.

Comment: Please provide a synopsis of the link as part of your answer. Off-site links cannot be depended upon.